# Java: How to retrieve a specific value from my arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to get a value, deep from an arraylist.

The attributes are in the following order:

```
arraylist > [0, 1, 2, 3 etc.] > 
    (example from array[0]): 
        [String name = "x"], [Private Time time] > (in time): 
            [String beginTime="12:00", String endTime="12:30", 
             long difference="1800000"].
```

I know how to get to the 0, 1, 2 of the array with help of .get(i) but how do I go deeper?
I have tried `.get(i).get(time).get(difference)`, but, as expected, it did not work.

Basically what I need to do is to sniff through the array and only take the difference value, and add everything up.

Comment: Maybe post your code how you create the array. It is not clear from the description what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you are storing an array of class Time.

You could do something like

```
((Time)get(i)).difference
```

Assuming that difference is an accessible field in the Time class.